# antlr4 visitor does not work

Tags: groovy, antlr4

I am trying to process `.pas` file. I generated lexers, parsers, visitors, listeners for grammar

Here is my custom visitor implementation

```
class GroovyPascalVisitor extends PascalBaseVisitor<ScriptSkeleton> {

    private static final String PASCAL_SCRIPT_NAME = "PascalScript"

    @Lazy ScriptSkeleton scriptSkeleton = new ScriptSkeleton()

    @Override
    public ScriptSkeleton visitProgramHeading(
            PascalParser.ProgramHeadingContext ctx) {
        log.info "Visiting program heading"
        def scriptName = ctx.identifier().getText()?.trim()
        if (!scriptName) {
            scriptName = PASCAL_SCRIPT_NAME +
                    "${new Random().nextInt(1000)}"
        }
        scriptSkeleton.scriptName = scriptName
        return scriptSkeleton
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my script

```
def file = new ANTLRFileStream(pas)
def lexer = new PascalLexer(file)
def parser = new PascalParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer))

tree = parser.program()
stringTree = tree.toStringTree(parser)

visitor = new GroovyPascalVisitor()
skeleton = visitor.visit(tree)
```

The `.pas` file content looks like this

```
program HelloWorld;

begin
    writeln('Hello, World!');
end.
```

But when I run script - it does not println message from log and object `scriptSkeleton` is null, meaning that it does not invoke `visitProgramHeading` at all.

What it is the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide you grammar?

Comment: @cantSleepNow sure. I used that one https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pascal/pascal.g4